# convert string to array and get value in php

Tags: php

I have a complete string how can i get some part of it and insert into an array this is my string in php

```
[{"albumid":"ASaBFzCtl8","albumname":"anni","type":"3","access":"2","itemcount":"2"},{"albumid":"EmgsZ43ehT","albumname":"testalbum","type":"1","access":"1","itemcount":"0"},{"albumid":"Jf4H4SvFGk","albumname":"test2album","type":"3","access":"1","itemcount":"0"},{"albumid":"k3pacBSmIl","albumname":"testalbumpvt","type":"3","access":"2","itemcount":"0"}]
```

i want something similar to this

```
$value1 = $array[0];
// {"albumid":"ASaBFzCtl8","albumname":"anni","type":"3","access":"2","itemcount":"2"}
```

is this possible to get each value like this

```
$value1 = $array[0]['albumid'];
 // ASaBFzCtl8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes use json_decode()

```
$j = '[{"albumid":"ASaBFzCtl8","albumname":"anni","type":"3","access":"2","itemcount":"2"},{"albumid":"EmgsZ43ehT","albumname":"testalbum","type":"1","access":"1","itemcount":"0"},{"albumid":"Jf4H4SvFGk","albumname":"test2album","type":"3","access":"1","itemcount":"0"},{"albumid":"k3pacBSmIl","albumname":"testalbumpvt","type":"3","access":"2","itemcount":"0"}]';

$data = json_decode($j,true);
```

You can use loop to read the data as

```
foreach($data as $key=>$val){
 echo $val["albumid"]."<br />";
}
```

Above will just get the albumid you can read whatever you want from this array.